# Как отодвинуть элемент в другой конец блока

Tags: html, css

Пробовал это сделать с помощью    `justify-content:flex-end`,  но это почему-то не сработало. Как это лучше всего сделать?

```css
.nav-content-bot {
  display: flex;
}

.top-menu {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-content-bot">
  <div class="logo">
    <h2 class="logoText">Explore</h2>
  </div>
  <nav class="top-menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Destinaton</a>
    <a href="#">Discount</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.nav-content-bot {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-content-bot">
  <div class="logo">
    <h2 class="logoText">Explore</h2>
  </div>
  <nav class="top-menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Destinaton</a>
    <a href="#">Discount</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Или так:

```css
.nav-content-bot {
  display: flex;
}

.top-menu {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-content-bot">
  <div class="logo">
    <h2 class="logoText">Explore</h2>
  </div>
  <nav class="top-menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Destinaton</a>
    <a href="#">Discount</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Или так (без лишних блоков):

```css
header {
  position: relative;
}

h2,
nav {
  display: inline;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Explore</h2>
  <nav class="top-menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Destinaton</a>
    <a href="#">Discount</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```